# Eclipse, Subversion and relocating of projects

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, ubuntu

I use Eclipse 3.5.1 downloaded from Yoxos under Ubuntu 9.10.
I had to correct some problems : 
 - GTK bug (export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1)
 - sqlite3 (I replaced the version of Ubuntu by a fresh one from the site and compiled; before I got a crash each time I get a hint about a function)

But I still have one with subversion : 
I relocated severals projects because of a server change via the command line client to svn.site.com (a svn info show svn.site.com), but Eclipse still show me old url www.site.com.
Each action (commit, diff, update) under Eclipse just freeze it.
When I import project from the disk, subversion is not avalaible for them, and "share project" just freeze.

On projects located to another server (mysvn.com) wich was not relocated, all is fine.
All was fine with the same installation with Ubuntu 8.04. I try to get a newer version but they have same problems. The eclipse bundled with Ubuntu 9.10 too.

I use subversive.

java -version

> java version "1.6.0_18" OpenJDK
>   Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8)
>   (6b18-1.8-4ubuntu3~9.10.2) OpenJDK
>   Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)

How can I understand why Eclispe freeze?

Regards,
Cédric

Comment: Do you have lots of uncommitted outgoing changes? If not, then I would suggest creating a new workspace from scratch, deleting the configured SVN repository (www.site.com), adding svn.site.com as a new SVN repository and checking out the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your existing eclipse projects are still referring to the old server in the workspace.  You need to re-check out the project from the new server, and then copy over the old stuff (minus anything in the .svn directories).

Eclipse appears to freeze because it is trying to locate the old server and is waiting for network timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Nine years late to the party, but for reference I will describe how you can do it from within Eclipse 3.8.1 (Ubuntu 16.04) using Subclipse.

1. From the **SVN Repositories** view, right-click the repository location that has changed and select *Relocate...*.

   Note that closed projects do not display in the list of projects to be relocated, so make sure to open any projects that you want to relocate.
2. Click Next.
3. Enter the new URL and click Finish.